# How to validate url params with react-router?

Tags: reactjs

I have a website that allows for urls of them form `/widgets/:id`. I have no more than 50 widgets, so `/widgets/51` is not a valid url. How do I go about rendering an error page when `id` is bigger than 50?

Should I be validating the value of `id` in my Widget component? Or should I be validating it at the routes level? Also, I would prefer that the act of displaying an error page does not change the url. That is to say, if a user navigates to `/widgets/51` I would like to display an error page, but I would like the url that gets displayed in the browser to keep reading `/widgets/51`.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer that the URL doesn't not change when you handle the error message then, you should be having the logic to test the params in the `Widget` component. You should do it as follows

```
render() {
    if(this.props.match.params.id > 50) {
        return <ErrorView/>
    }else {
        return <WidgetView/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I would add is that you should avoid such logic on the render method. That said, I would recomend you use "branch" HoC on the Recompose lib: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @LucasConstantinoSilva